# Editing old wish commands in the shell

Tags: shell, tcl

I'm running wish (as part of the TCL/TK 8.6 distribution) in a mac terminal window.

Unfortunately, I can't recall and edit previous commands.

A long time ago (think 15 years ago) there was some clever program that trapped all user commands so you could recall and edit old commands before sending them to a program that could not edit old commands.

I think it was called FOP (but I might be wrong here_ and it ran on Linux

So I'd say

```
  > FOP wish
```

and then I'd be able to recall and edit previous commands.

Is there any such program that I can use that does this - so that I can edit old wish commands?

Comment: `rlwrap` is good here. You might be able to get it through homebrew. Otherwise, instigate `tkcon` which will meet your needs.

Comment: Run `sudo port install rlwrap` to obtain `rlwrap` from MacPorts.

Answer (score 2):

The usual package for this sort of thing is [`rlwrap`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap), which lets you put a readline-based wrapper around programs such as tclsh. It's an optional package — called `rlwrap`, obviously — in the usual distribution sources for CentOS, Debian and Ubuntu (as well as both MacPorts and Homebrew, for people on macOS) so installation is pretty straight-forward.

Once you've installed it, you then do:

```
rlwrap wish
```

and enjoy your more sophisticated input capabilities.

---

There are probably other packages capable of doing this sort of thing, but rlwrap is very easy and pretty well recommended; I've not heard of anyone using anything else except for reasons of outright bloodymindedness.

Comment: Brilliant that worked beautifully - thank you very much